# Retrun object from lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

ALL,

I have a following structure:

```
struct Foo
{
    string name;
    long position, originalPosition;
};
```

I also have a vector of those structs.

And here is what I an trying to do:

```
Foo fieldToRemove;
m_groupByFields.erase( std::remove_if( m_groupByFields.begin(), m_groupByFields.end(), 
                      [fieldName, fieldToRemove](Foo field) mutable
{
    if( field.fieldName == fieldName )
        fieldToRemove = field;
    return field.fieldName == fieldName;
}), m_groupByFields.end() );
```

Unfortunately after executing the `fieldToRemove` does not contain the proper data.

What am I missing? Is it even possible?

TIA!!

Comment: `fieldToRemove` needs to be captured by ref, not by value? Also `Foo field` probably should be a const ref.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yes, capturing by reference solves it. I'm still trying t get a hold of this syntax to make it properly. Now about the second comment - why?

Comment: To avoid a copy each time the lambda is called.